# Issuses with not recognizing namespace functions

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, reference

I am having certain issues with not being able to recognize the functions of a particular namespace. This isn't the first time I have had this problem, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am using Visual Studio 2019

I have tried to find the references that would be needed, but it seems like what I have isn't working.

```
public ImageSource UserImage
{
    get { return UserImage.Source; }
    set { UserImage.Source = value; }
}
```

The program doesn't recognize .Source  I have also had this happen with Datagrid.DataSource Everything else works, except a few functions. Did these get changed or am I missing a reference or assembly?

Edit:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Animations_Aestatic_Test_App
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

         public ImageSource UserImage
         {
              get { return UserImage.Source; }
              set { UserImage.Source = value; }
         }



    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you use the fully qualified name `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource`? What `using` directives do you have?

Comment: Are you using .Net or Core? I have notices that a 2019 console app defaults to Core and this can make a difference.

Comment: How can the value of UserImage be a *property* of UserImage? Is there more than one `UserImage`? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I am just trying to play around with creating a usercontrol so I can make better user interfaces. Also, for those who are edited will you please tell me why you are editing? Otherwise I'm going to keep getting marked down because I literally try to make it to all the standards possible.

Comment: @Stacie We're just fixing up the formatting. Nobody's going to mark you down over formatting. What is `UserImage` supposed to be? Is there a control or something named `userImage`? We need to see a lot more of your code and the XAML too.

Comment: I understand, but I lost 5 points yesterday due to someone not liking my formatting. [Link](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=c%23+wpf+how+to+make+a+user+interface&&view=detail&mid=6D1DCE2A7C88BF99530E6D1DCE2A7C88BF99530E&&FORM=VDRVRV) I am just following this video to replicate the code and pick it apart. That is mainly how I've learned to code up until now.

Comment: @Stacie You can see what was changed in edits made to your question along with the edit summary that details why the edits were made (if the editor provided any) by clicking on the link that says `edited XX ago` above the name of the user who made the edits.

Comment: The `DataGrid`in WPF has no `DataSource` property. It's called `ItemsSource`. What project template are you using and what does Visual Studio say when you try to build?

Comment: [It would appear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imagesource?view=netframework-4.8#properties) that `ImageSource` does not have a `Source` property according to the documentation. So the error makes sense.

Comment: How are you using the property? It's current implementation makes no sense.

Comment: Okay, but if you watch the video I sent the Link to then why does it work for that guy? Also, I am almost positive I am using .NET Framework.

Comment: @Stacie This code is not your entire application. There is XAML as well. Your assumption is wrong: The problem isn't that any properties have been deprecated. The problem is a) ImageSource has no Source property, and b) you have a property setting and getting a property of itself, which isn't going to work even if that type did have such a property. I am trying to help you. "Go watch a video" isn't going to help me understand your code, because your code is clearly different from the code in the video.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I understand that, have you watched the video by any chance? This isn't the first time I've come across this very problem. Will someone watch the video and let me know why he is able to do this and I cannot. Why does it work for him?

Comment: @Stacie The code in your question will never work for anybody. I suggest you watch the video again and duplicate the code they gave you.

Comment: That is what this entire post is about. If I rewatch the video, for the 5th time it will be the same as the 1st and 2nd and 3rd and 4th. I'm still here wondering the same question and no one is watching the video. Someone just close this post and I'll accept that none of you are willing to help because you won't watch the video and see what he is doing. Thank you for trying to help. Have a good day.

Comment: @Stacie ["Questions about a problem... that was caused by a simple typographical error" are off-topic for this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please take more care in transcribing code in the future.

Answer (score 1):

An `ImageSource` has no `Source` property. It is the source of an Image and a property cannot return itself, so I guess you want to return the `Source` of an `Image` element:

```
Image _userImage;
public ImageSource UserImage
{
    get { return _userImage.Source; }
    set { _userImage.Source = value; }
}
```